# airflow: All tasks finished but dag state is running

Tags: mysql, celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm using Airflow 2.0.0 with CeleryExecutor and mysql-8.0.22.

Every time we execute any dag. Irrespective of all tasks status being failed/success/mixed, overall dag status is always running.

Because of which after sometime, scheduler also gets crashed.

Airflow is installed at /root/
Here is the airflow.cfg:

```
[core]
dags_folder = /var/airflow/dags
executor = CeleryExecutor
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://user:password@localhost:3306/airflow

[logging]
base_log_folder = /var/airflow/logs

[webserver]
base_url = http://localhost:8080
default_ui_timezone = UTC
web_server_host = 0.0.0.0
web_server_port = 8080

[celery]
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor
worker_concurrency = 8
worker_log_server_port = 8793
broker_url = sqla+mysql://user:password@localhost:3306/celery
result_backend=db+mysql://user:password@localhost:3306/celery
flower_host = 0.0.0.0
flower_port = 5555
operation_timeout = 1.0

[scheduler]
child_process_log_directory = /var/airflow/logs/scheduler
```

Can somebody help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your database running on the same node as your airflow worker? It looks wrong.